# Add HTML form field to existing form when a button is pressed without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I found quite a few [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) examples when googling for this. However, none of them worked for me.

I want to achieve a relatively simple task: By pressing an add field button in a form a second select field should show up. This should go on indefinitely. Since I'm already using the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) library, I would prefer to use it here too.

The page should not reload once you press the add field button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the sample *[How to hide, show, or toggle your div](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/)*.

Comment: Thanks, theres some good examples here. Maybe it makes sense to not go infinitely with new fields but limit it to 10 or so. Thanks. BTW Theres an update that covers jquery http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

Use the append method for easy scripting. If, however, you want to do this on a more serious basis, read up on [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) scripting.

See:

- [Tinker here](https://tinker.io/22681/155)
- Further reading: *[How to dynamically add form elements via JavaScript](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/)*

Answer (score 1):

Try the `after()`, `append()` and `appendTo()` methods (see *[Category: Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)*).

Comment: I'm guessing the issue, based on some keywords in the question, is that the form is posting when the button is clicked.

Comment: That issue should be remedied by using a 'regular' button, not a submit button. Or catch the standard behaviour (posting the form) with `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do. Either you append a new element, like so:

```
$("form").append($('<input type="text">');
```

OR, you already put the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) in the form, but make it invisible with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and then show it, like so:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="hidden">
</form>

$("#theNewField").removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newSelectField = "<select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option></select>"; 

$("#formID").append(newSelectField);

//make sure your button is not of type="submit"
<input type="button" value="Add new field" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sample code, I can only guess what the issue is, but it sounds like you are using a submit input instead of a button input, which is causing your form to submit and the page to reload instead of just triggering the "add element" function. If that's the case, here's what to do:

Change the add button to look like:

```
 <input type="button" id="addOption" value="Add" />
```

If it's not already in place, add the event listener in your script for when the button is clicked:

```
 $("#addOption").click (function(){
 // Add stuff
}):
```

Follow Patrick's advice on the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) manipulation methods.