# grails: onchange=${remoteFunction()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm new to grails and I'm trying to insert another textfield element into a form when the first field is filled in.  I'm trying the remoteFunction action to call a template but the template is not getting called. If I change the "g:textField" to a "g:select" option I will get a dropdown box, but do not want the dropdown box.

My idea is to have a name field and when it gets filled out, it should have another name field to be entered below the first one. I don't want to hard code several name fields into the form.

My View--

```
<tr class="prop">
<td valign="top" class="name">
<label for="casStudent_1"><g:message code="casawards.casStudent_1.label" default="Student #1" /></label>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: casawardsInstance, field: 'casStudent_1', 'errors')}">
<g:textArea onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'create2' controller="casawards",
update: 'casStudent_2',
params: '\'timeName=\' + this.value')}"
name="casStudent_1" valueMessagePrefix="casawards.casStudent_1"
value="${casawardsInstance?.casStudent_1}" />
</td>
</tr>
```

controller --

```
def _create2 = { render (template:"create2") }
```

Template (create2) --

```
<tr class="prop">
<td  valign="top" class="name">
<label id = "casStudent_2" for="casStudent_2"><g:message    code="casawards.casStudent_2.label" default="Student #2" /></label>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: casawardsInstance, field: 'casStudent_2', 'errors')}">
<g:textField name="casStudent_2" value="${casawardsInstance?.casStudent_2}" />
</tr>
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to go to the server to create a new field? You can easily manipulate the DOM using javascript. Is there any server side processing you need before you insert the second field?

Comment: I'm new and do not know the javascript to insert a field. Can you provide it?

Comment: try this link for some help http://stackoverflow.com/q/9630854/74057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'update' parameter in your remoteFunction should point to an existing DOM element. In your case, a call will be made to 'casawards/create2' and the response will be set as the content of and existing DOM element with id "casStudent_2". Are you sure that this element exists in your DOM?

Another issue is that onChange is called when you move the focus out of the textarea. Try clicking somewhere else in the page and see if the call is made.

Comment: The element casStudent_2 is defined in the domain class.  For the onchange I am trying to off focus by both tabbing and by clicking on the next field with the same effect happening which is nothing, the new field is not being inserted.

Comment: What do you mean by "The element casStudent_2 is defined in the domain class"? You need to have a DOM element with id "casStudent_2" on the page before the ajax call is made. To me it looks like that you have a label with id "casStudent_2" and that too in the response of the first ajax request. Try adding a <div id = "casStudent_2"></div> rght after your g:textArea